# Using Mapping toolbox and the wmmarker function: why doesn't the clickable 'description' link open its target?

Tags: matlab, mapping

I use Matlab Mapping Toolbox and the `wmmarker` function. In the documentation of this function ('doc wmmarker') the following example is used to show how markers on a map can get pop up labels with text, where some of the text can be hyperlinks. In the example below, a label is made for the geographical point named "ST01", and the label is  maked both with the station name and with a hyperlink pointing towards the url: https://www.mathworks.com.

```
close all
webmap('World Imagery');

stationName  = 'ST01';
target="_blank">https://www.mathworks.com</a>');

description = sprintf('%s','<a href="https://www.mathworks.com" target="_blank">https://www.mathworks.com</a>');                   

lat          = 69.601142;
lon          = 30.025769;
color        = [0, 1, 0];

wmmarker(lat,lon,...
    'FeatureName',stationName,...
    'Description',description,...
    'Color',color,...
    'AutoFit',true);
```

However, when clicking this hyperlink the web page does not open. What can be the the reasons for this?

EDIT 2019-12-06:
if I evaluate the 'description' variable in the command window, the link produced will open the url (www.mathworks.com) when clikcked. Why doesn't my 'description' string work in wmmarker, but still work in the command window?

Comment: As side comments: the line `target="_blank">https://www.mathworks.com</a>');` gives an error. Also, you don't seem to be using the `target` variable anyway

Comment: Your code works fine in R2017b. What version are you on?

Comment: I am using R2019b

Comment: I only could reproduce your problem by changing `target`to `target=('<a href="https://www.mathworks.com" target="_blank">https://www.mathworks.com</a>');` doing it with R2018b

Comment: ok, interesting, I will test out the effects of manipulating the target - variable

Comment: If I remove the  'target="_blank" ' part of the description string above, the link 'https://www.mathworks.com' function will function when clicked in the map. However, it is still not clickable if I change the link from an URL to a loaca file by the following description: description  = sprintf('%s','<a href="matlab: winopen(''myFigures\minFigur.jpg'')">CLICKY</a>'). If I excecute this discription string directly in the command window, a clickable link will open my file, but inside the wmmarker function the link will not open.